# When trying to save R Markdown file, "Error file not found" pops up

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am very new to R so if someone could explain this to me in very simple words, it would be greatly appreciated.

I just completed a project in r markdown but when I am trying to knit it, "Error file or directory not found" pops up and I cannot open the file even if it is saved manually.

this is what pops us in my console

```
processing file: Bellabeat-project.Rmd
  |.                                                                     |   2%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..                                                                    |   3%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi TRUE


Quitting from lines 115-120 (Bellabeat-project.Rmd) 
Error in read_csv("/Users/irina/Desktop/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16/dailyActivity_merged.csv") : 
  could not find function "read_csv"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()

  Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

  MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

  Linux: Use system package manager
```

I've tried saving other r markdown files and it worked perfectly so I am unsure what the problem is

I have also installed everything that is being said in the error window but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

What packages do you have loaded in the global chunk of the Rmd script? You might look into loading:

```
library(pander)
library(tinytex)
```

And you probably already loaded tidyverse but check that, too - the above packages helped resolve a similar issue for me.

Comment: I already had downloaded tidyverse, dplyr, formattable, ggplot2, here, purr, readr, tibble, tidyr, tidyselect, tinytex. and I downloaded the ones you suggested but it still displays error

Comment: Ah, I see - another thing that I've tried that has worked in the past is 1) uninstalling & reinstalling tinytex or 2) double-checking that the MikTex installation is up to date: https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex